# ARIMA results interpretation

Tags: python, python-2.7, statistics, time-series, forecasting

How do i interpret the results of ARIMA. I have a differenced series and i implemented 2 ARIMA models ARIMA[2,1,0] and ARIMA [1,1,0] . Which is better and i also plotted the ACF and PACF from which i assume 2,1,0 should be good [ACF decreases gradually and PACF falls down at around 2] . Though i have heard even after plotting ACF and PACF we usually try out a few or loop over all otherwise to find the best. Do we see AIC/BIC to compare or some other statistic?

Here is the ARIMA [1,1,0] result

[ARIMA 1,1,0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW7kn.jpg)

Here is the ARIMA [2,1,0] result
[ARIMA 2,1,0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xtw2O.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As long as the difference term is the same (which was 1 for both your models) you can compare the two models using AIC/BIC.

AIC/BIC comparison can only be applied on the data of same size. So if you have one model with difference term = 1 and another with 2, the latter one will have less data points after modeling and could give a lower AIC/BIC with no promise of a better model.

If your data allow you to do cross validation, you might want to try that before you reach to a conclusion of which set of parameter is the best for your arima model.

You may want to take a look at this discussion on Cross Validated, which gave a simple idea on how to implement cross validation for arima. 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14099/using-k-fold-cross-validation-for-time-series-model-selection